# Why programs such as Firefox no longer are linked with master sound volume?

Tags: 14.04, sound

Few days ago everything worked just fine, when I would change sound volume it would affect all programs. Now, when I increase or decrease global sound volume it doesn't take effect on apps. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this solution by opening sound settings and select my headset device (for some reason it got deselected). And now master volume affects all programs.

[image]